# Adding tuple elements, parsed into pandas DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas

I have several Python lists of tuples:

```
[(0, 61), (1, 30), (5, 198), (4, 61), (0, 30), (5, 200)]
[(1, 72), (2, 19), (3, 31), (4, 192), (6, 72), (5, 75)]
[(3, 12), (0, 51)]
...
```

Each of these tuples are created such that these are in the format `(key, value)`:

There are seven keys: 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6

The intended output is a pandas DataFrame, whereby each column is named by the key:

```
import pandas as pd
print(df)

0    1    2    3    4    5    6 
91   30   0    0    61   198  0
0    72   19   31   192  75   72
51   0    0    12   0    0    0
```

Now, the problem I have conceptually is how to add several tuple "values" if they keys which are the same.

I can access these values for a given list, e.g.

```
mylist = [(0, 61), (1, 30), (5, 198), (4, 61), (0, 30), (5, 200)]
keys =  [x[0] for x in mylist]
```

and

```
print(keys)
[0, 1, 5, 4, 0, 5]
```

I'm not sure how to create, e.g. a dictionary of the key:value pairs, which I could load into a pandas DataFrame

Comment: Where do the 0's come from?

Comment: @chrisz The 0s are above in the tuples, `(0, 61)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can apply `groupby` to sum value by key first for each element then using `pandas` to convert to dataframe. **Note** that you have to sort by key first before summing.

```
import pandas as pd
from itertools import groupby

data = [
    [(0, 61), (1, 30), (5, 198), (4, 61), (0, 30), (5, 200)],
    [(1, 72), (2, 19), (3, 31), (4, 192), (6, 72), (5, 75)],
    [(0, 71), (1, 40), (5, 98), (4, 21), (0, 10), (5, 21200)],
    [(1, 702), (2, 190), (3, 310), (4, 1092), (6, 702), (5, 705)],
] # copying example from @PatrickArtnerz solution

def group_sum(data):
    """given list, return dictionary of summation based on initial key"""
    data_dict = {k: sum(v_[1] for v_ in v) for k, v in groupby(sorted(data, key=lambda x: x[0]), lambda x: x[0])}
    return data_dict

df = pd.DataFrame(list(map(group_sum, data))).fillna(0)
```

Answer (score 4):

Consider your data in a name `tups`

```
tups = [
    [(0, 61), (1, 30), (5, 198), (4, 61), (0, 30), (5, 200)],
    [(1, 72), (2, 19), (3, 31), (4, 192), (6, 72), (5, 75)],
    [(3, 12), (0, 51)]
]
```

---

**Option 0**
Using `np.bincount` and crazy maps and zips and splats
This works because `np.bincount`s first two arguments are the array of positions and the optional array of weights to use while adding.

```
pd.DataFrame(
    list(map(lambda t: np.bincount(*zip(*t)), tups))
).fillna(0, downcast='infer')

    0   1   2   3    4    5   6
0  91  30   0   0   61  398   0
1   0  72  19  31  192   75  72
2  51   0   0  12    0    0   0
```

---

**Option 1**
Using comprehensions and summation over axis levels.

```
pd.Series({
    (i, j, k): v
    for i, row in enumerate(tups)
    for k, (j, v) in enumerate(row)
}).sum(level=[0, 1]).unstack(fill_value=0)

    0   1   2   3    4    5   6
0  91  30   0   0   61  398   0
1   0  72  19  31  192   75  72
2  51   0   0  12    0    0   0
```

---

**Option 2**
You can use the `DataFrame` constructor on the result of using a defaultdict:

```
from collections import defaultdict

d = defaultdict(lambda: defaultdict(int))

for i, row in enumerate(tups):
    for j, v in row:
        d[j][i] += v

pd.DataFrame(d).fillna(0, downcast='infer')

    0   1   2   3    4    5   6
0  91  30   0   0   61  398   0
1   0  72  19  31  192   75  72
2  51   0   0  12    0    0   0
```

---

**Option 3**
Create a zero dataframe and update it via iteration

```
n, m = len(tups), max(j for row in tups for j, _ in row) + 1

df = pd.DataFrame(0, range(n), range(m))

for i, row in enumerate(tups):
    for j, v in row:
        df.at[i, j] += v

df

    0   1   2   3    4    5   6
0  91  30   0   0   61  398   0
1   0  72  19  31  192   75  72
2  51   0   0  12    0    0   0
```

Comment: I appreciate the sentiment. Personally, I’m more comfortable giving one answer.

Comment: I noted in my response to @Allen 's answer that there are some issues with `downcast='infer'` and the size of the resulting DataFrame. Why would this be?
Also, thank you so much for the comprehensive answers! I think this is great in helping me and other readers learn :)

Answer (score 3):

Use piRSquared's example:

```
tups = [
    [(0, 61), (1, 30), (5, 198), (4, 61), (0, 30), (5, 200)],
    [(1, 72), (2, 19), (3, 31), (4, 192), (6, 72), (5, 75)],
    [(3, 12), (0, 51)]
]

#First build a dict for each row with unique keys.
data = [{f[0]:[] for f in e} for e in tups]
#add values to the dict as list which can capture multiple values.
[[data[k][e[0]].append(e[1]) for e in v] for k,v in enumerate(tups)]
#sum values for each key for each row.
data = [{k:sum(v) for k,v in e.items()} for e in data]
# build a df and fillna with 0
pd.DataFrame(data).fillna(0, downcast='infer')

Out[127]: 
    0   1   2   3    4    5   6
0  91  30   0   0   61  398   0
1   0  72  19  31  192   75  72
2  51   0   0  12    0    0   0
```

Comment: Thanks for this response. I appreciate the comments. I notice a problem with my own data however; the length `len(tups)` ends up being a bit larger than the number of rows in the pandas DataFrame. Any ideas why this would be? It's possible there are maybe empty lists/tuples in `tups` which are causing this issue...

Comment: Actually, it looks like I do not see this issue with `pd.DataFrame(data).fillna(0)`. The # of rows is now the same as `len(tups)`, but the DataFrame looks like it is in the wrong format. Do you know why this would be?

Answer (score 2):

I would:

- consolidate inner lists (add same keys together)
- create sets from consolidated lists to a list of sets (I combined it with 1st step)
- make a dataframe
- replace `NaN`s

---

```
import pandas as pd

data = [  [(0, 61), (1, 30), (5, 198), (4, 61), (0, 30), (5, 200)],
          [(1, 72), (2, 19), (3, 31), (4, 192), (6, 72), (5, 75)],
          [(0, 71), (1, 40), (5, 98), (4, 21), (0, 10), (5, 21200)],      # addon
          [(1, 702), (2, 190), (3, 310), (4, 1092), (6, 702), (5, 705)],  # addon
          ]

consolidated = []
for li in data:
    row = {}  # instead of replacing NaNs you could prefill: row = {k:0 for k in range(7)}
     for tup in li:
        key,val = tup
        row.setdefault(key,0)
        row[key]+=val
    consolidated.append (row)

df = pd.DataFrame(consolidated)
df = df.fillna(0)                  # replace NaN's with 0
print(df)
```

Output:

```
      0    1      2      3     4      5      6
0  91.0   30    0.0    0.0    61    398    0.0
1   0.0   72   19.0   31.0   192     75   72.0
2  81.0   40    0.0    0.0    21  21298    0.0
3   0.0  702  190.0  310.0  1092    705  702.0
```